# Wordpress theme switcher

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to set up a theme demos site, so I am looking for a theme switcher. I have tried a few of them, they create the demo url like:

```
example.com/whatever?themedemo=theme-name
```

But I am looking for any plugin which generates cleaner urls, for example:

example.com/whatever/theme-name

If there is any, please let me know.

So I am looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with `.htaccess` rather than wordpress itself.

You could just add a row to your htaccess files.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/theme-(.+)$ $1?themedemo=theme-$2%{query_string}
```

$1 is argument one, the first appearance of (.+) and is the page name
$2 is the second argument, the second appearnce of (.+) as in the theme name

so if you write:

**example.com/about/theme-thesis** it should get the content **from example.com/about?themedemo=theme-thesis**

try it out!